# Yammer Embed does not load in IE 11 in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint, yammer

I'm using the Yammer Embed script to integrate Yammer feeds within SharePoint 2010. However, it does not load when viewing the page in IE 11. I get the following error in Console:
"Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'"

And then I have three frames with "Loading..." on top and a fourth frame with "This content cannot be displayed in a frame".

Any ideas ?

*Editing to update..*

I have made a few more tests and have found that the issue was because of a X-UA-Compatible meta tag in the page, forcing compatibility mode to IE 8. When I force the Document Mode to IE 10/Edge in F12 Developer Tools, Yammer Embed starts to work again.

However, is there anyway to make Yammer Embed work while keeping the IE 8 Compatibility mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yammer has recently ended support for IE9 and now gives you a banner warning. IE8 just gives a variety of javascript errors.

As noted in https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/requirements the out of the box SharePoint 2010 masterpage renders in IE8 mode.

If are you restricted to IE8 by your site using the SharePoint masterpage, you could investigate replacing the default masterpage with a custom one which doesn't render in IE8 mode. Yammer embed will render fine as long as you break the IE8 dependency of SharePoint 2010.

If you are restricted to IE8 for some other reason, you will not be able to have Yammer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @fudoki22. Unfortunately, we must continue to use IE 8 compatibility for now since other site features depend on it.